# FETCH SYS_REFCURSOR with recursive WITH ORA-32042

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have table with this definition:

```
create table my_tab as
  select '1' p, '2' c from dual
  union
  select '1' p, '3' c from dual
  union
  select '4' p, '5' c from dual
  union
  select '4' p, '6' c from dual
  union
  select '4' p, '2' c from dual
  union
  select '7' p, '3' c from dual
  union
  select '8' p, '4' c from dual;
```

I two TYPEs (Тhis is just for information. I simplified the example as much as possible!):

```
TYPE TObj_OUT AS OBJECT(File_Name VARCHAR2(128),
                            File_Records NUMBER,
                            Session_ID NUMBER,
                            Instanse_ID NUMBER);
CREATE OR REPLACE type TObj_OUT_NT AS TABLE OF TObj_OUT;
```

Package that print content from SYS_REFCURSOR(return some dummy data just for example):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_info(ip_Select IN SYS_REFCURSOR
                                     ) RETURN TObj_OUT_NT PIPELINED AS
      TYPE TROW IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
      v_rows    TROW;
   BEGIN
      LOOP
        FETCH ip_Select BULK COLLECT INTO v_rows LIMIT 100;
         FOR i IN 1 .. v_rows.COUNT LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_rows(i));
         END LOOP;
         EXIT WHEN ip_Select%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE ip_Select;
      PIPE ROW (TObj_OUT('bb', 0, 0, 5));
      RETURN;
END print_info;
```

I have tried this:

```
declare
v_cnt number(8);
my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin

open my_cursor for with t1(p,
    c) as
     (select distinct null p, t.p as c
        from my_tab t
      union all
      select t.p, t.c
        from t1
        join my_tab t
          on t.p = t1.c)
    select p || c from t1; 

SELECT file_records
    into v_cnt
    FROM TABLE(
print_info(
-- cursor start
cursor(
-- FIRST QUERY
with t1(p,
    c) as
     (select distinct null p, t.p as c
        from my_tab t
      union all
      select t.p, t.c
        from t1
        join my_tab t
          on t.p = t1.c)
    select p || c from t1
--FIRST_QUERY END
--SECOND QUERY
--select p||c from my_tab
--SECONF QUERY END
)
-- cursor end
-- my_cursor
));
end;
```

When I execute block I receive this error:

> ORA-32042: recursive WITH clause must reference itself directly in one of the UNION ALL branches
>
> ORA-06512: at "PRINT_INFO", line 9
>
> ORA-06512: at line 17

BUT when i comment code from **cursor start** to **cursor end**

```
-- cursor start
cursor(with t1(p,
    c) as
     (select distinct null p, t.p as c
        from my_tab t
      union all
      select t.p, t.c
        from t1
        join my_tab t
          on t.p = t1.c)
    select p || c from t1)
-- cursor end
```

and uncomment line

```
-- my_cursor
```

It works fine!
If comment **FIRST QUERY** and uncomment **SECOND QUERY** It works fine again!
I can't understand where is the problem!

Comment: That looks like a bug to me; there's nothing in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions006.htm#SQLRF52077) about a restriction on recursive with clause queries. There's also nothing in My Oracle Support for that error, so you should probably get a service request raised if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug with cursor expressions + ANSI -> native transformation.

Your case may be simplified just to one SQL statement.

```
SQL> select cursor(with t1(p, c) as (select distinct null p, t.p as c
  2                                    from my_tab t
  3                                  union all
  4                                  select t.p, t.c
  5                                    from t1
  6                                    join my_tab t
  7                                      on t.p = t1.c)
  8           select p || c from t1) c from dual;
select cursor(with t1(p, c) as (select distinct null p, t.p as c
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-32042: recursive WITH clause must reference itself directly in one of the
UNION ALL branches


SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'basic'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:
------------------------
select cursor(with t1(p, c) as (select distinct null p, t.p as c
                           from my_tab t
 union all                                 select t.p, t.c
                     from t1                                   join
my_tab t                                     on t.p = t1.c)
select p || c from t1) c from dual

Plan hash value: 956860371

------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name   |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |        |
|   1 |  VIEW                                     |        |
|   2 |   UNION ALL (RECURSIVE WITH) BREADTH FIRST|        |
|   3 |    SORT UNIQUE                            |        |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | MY_TAB |
|   5 |    VIEW                                   |        |
|   6 |     HASH JOIN                             |        |
|   7 |      RECURSIVE WITH PUMP                  |        |
|   8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | MY_TAB |
|   9 |  FAST DUAL                                |        |
------------------------------------------------------------


26 rows selected.

SQL> select cursor(with t1(p, c) as (select distinct null p, t.p as c
  2                                    from my_tab t
  3                                  union all
  4                                  select t.p, t.c
  5                                    from t1, my_tab t
  6                                   where t.p = t1.c)
  7           select p || c from t1) c from dual;

C
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

P|
--
1
8
7
4
12
13
42
45
46
73
84
42
45
46

14 rows selected.


SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'basic'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:
------------------------
select cursor(with t1(p, c) as (select distinct null p, t.p as c
                           from my_tab t
 union all                                 select t.p, t.c
                     from t1, my_tab t
where t.p = t1.c)          select p || c from t1) c from dual

Plan hash value: 2529699678

------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name   |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |        |
|   1 |  VIEW                                     |        |
|   2 |   UNION ALL (RECURSIVE WITH) BREADTH FIRST|        |
|   3 |    SORT UNIQUE                            |        |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | MY_TAB |
|   5 |    HASH JOIN                              |        |
|   6 |     RECURSIVE WITH PUMP                   |        |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | MY_TAB |
|   8 |  FAST DUAL                                |        |
------------------------------------------------------------


24 rows selected.
```

So first query (with ANSI join syntax) failed however second one (with native join syntax) completed successfully.

The difference in query plans is VIEW operation for the first query (ID = 5).
It informs us that inline view has been created during query transformation.

Let's have a look at transformed queries in trace file for event 10053.

```
select cursor(with "T1"("P", "C")
              as((select "from$_subquery$_004"."QCSJ_C000000000400001_2" "P",
                         "from$_subquery$_004"."QCSJ_C000000000400003_3" "C"
                    from (select "T1"."P" "QCSJ_C000000000400000",
                                 "T1"."C" "QCSJ_C000000000400002",
                                 "T"."P"  "QCSJ_C000000000400001_2",
                                 "T"."C"  "QCSJ_C000000000400003_3"
                            from "T1" "T1", "MY_TAB" "T"
                           where "T"."P" = "T1"."C") "from$_subquery$_004")
                 union all (select distinct null "P", "T"."P" "C"
                    from "MY_TAB" "T")) select "T1"."P" || "T1"."C"
              "P||C" from "T1" "T1") "C"
  from "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"

select cursor(with "T1"("P", "C")
              as((select "T"."P" "P", "T"."C" "C"
                    from "T1" "T1", "MY_TAB" "T"
                   where "T"."P" = "T1"."C") union all
                 (select distinct null "P", "T"."P" "C"
                    from "MY_TAB" "T")) select "T1"."P" || "T1"."C"
              "P||C" from "T1" "T1") "C"
  from "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
```

You see that join has been transformed in the first query into additional inline view with where clause and if you try to run first query it fails with ORA-32042.